# Need to make an efficient vector handling algorithm for gravity simulation

Tags: performance, trigonometry, gravity

So I'm currently working on a Java Processing program where I want to simulate high numbers of particles interacting with collision and gravity. This obviously causes some performance issue when particle count gets high, so I try my best to optimize and avoid expensive operations such as square-root, otherwise used in finding distance between two points.

However, now I'm wondering how I could do the algoritm that figures out the direction a particle should move, given it only knows the distance squared and the difference between particles' x and y (dx, dy).

Here's a snip of the code (yes, I know I should use vectors instead of seperate x/y-couples. Yes, I know I should eventually handle particles by grids and clusters for further optimization) Anyways:

```js
    void applyParticleGravity(){
        int limit = 2*particleRadius+1; //Gravity no longer applied if particles are within collision reach of eachother.
        float ax, ay, bx, by, dx, dy;
        float distanceSquared, f;
        float gpp = GPP; //Constant is used, since simulation currently assumes all particles have equal mass: GPP = Gravity constant * Particle Mass * Particle Mass
        Vector direction = new Vector();

        Particle a, b;
        int nParticles = particles.size()-1; //"particles" is an arraylist with particles objects, each storing an x/y coordinate and velocity.

        for (int i=0; i<nParticles; i++){
            a = particles.get(i);
            ax = a.x;
            ay = a.y;

            for (int j=i+1; j<nParticles; j++){
                b = particles.get(j);
                bx = b.x;
                by = b.y;

                dx = ax-bx;
                dy = ay-by;

                if (Math.abs(dx) > limit && Math.abs(dy) > limit){ //Not too close to eachother
                    distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy; //Avoiding square roots
                    f = gpp/distanceSquared; //Gravity formula: Force = G*(m1*m2)/d^2

                    //Perform some trigonometric magic to decide direction.x and direction.y as a numbet between -1 and 1.

                    a.fx += f*direction.x; //Adds force to particle. At end of main iteration, x-position is increased by fx/mass and so forth.
                    a.fy += f*direction.y;
                    b.fx -= f*direction.x; //Apply inverse force to other particle (Newton's 3rd law)
                    b.fy -= f*direction.y;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a more accurate way of deciding the x and y pull strength with some trigonometric magic without killing performance when particles are several hundreds? Something I thought about was doing some sort of (int)dx/dy with % operator or so and get an index of a pre-calculated array of values.

Anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: This volume of processing should be performed on your GPU. Check out the web site for your graphics card vendor, which will have plentiful examples of performing similar type of calculation on hundreds of particles.

Answer (score 0):

hehe, I think we're working on the same kind of thing, except I'm using HTML5 canvas.  I came across this trying to figure out the same thing. I didn't find anything but I figured out what I was going for, and I think it will work for you too.

You want an identity vector that points from one particle to the another.  The length will be 1, and x and y will be between -1 and 1.  Then you take this identity vector and multiply it by your force scalar, which you're already calculating

To "point at" one particle from another, without using square root, first get the heading (in radians) from particle1 to particle2:

```
heading = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
```

Note that y is first, I think this is how it works in Java. I used x first in Javascript and that worked for me.

Get the x and y components of this heading using sin/cos:

```
direction.x = Math.sin(heading)
direction.y = Math.cos(heading)
```

You can see an example here:
https://github.com/nijotz/triforces/blob/c7b85d06cf8a65713d9b84ae314d5a4a015876df/src/cljs/triforces/core.cljs#L41

It's Clojurescript, but it may help.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you didn't want to just point in the right direction, you wanted direction to scale as well.

Comment: Oh ya, and an example of what I'm working on is [here](http://nijotz.com/gravity/).